# Pandas merge, conditional update in Conflicting Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have two Data Frames, `df1` & `df2` (see below), which i would like to

1. `merge` on one of the common columns
2. conditionally update the other common columns.

Sample Data Frame and expected results.

```py
df1:
   A    B     C
0  123  1819. NaN  
1  456  NaN   115
2  789  9012. NaN
3  121  8732. NaN
4  883  NaN   171
5  771  8871. 191
```

```py
# df2:
     C      B
0  115  41853
1  115  22723
2  115  57302
3  115  91494
4  171  43607
5  171  36327
6  191  39874
7  191  25456
8  191  76283
9  191  97506
```

1. `merge` on column **`C`**

```py
# how='left' is necessary
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='C', how='left')
      A     B_x      C      B_y
0   123  1819.0    NaN      NaN
1   456     NaN  115.0  41853.0
2   456     NaN  115.0  22723.0
3   456     NaN  115.0  57302.0
4   456     NaN  115.0  91494.0
5   789  9012.0    NaN      NaN
6   121  8732.0    NaN      NaN
7   883     NaN  171.0  43607.0
8   883     NaN  171.0  36327.0
9   771     NaN  191.0  39874.0
10  771     NaN  191.0  25456.0
11  771     NaN  191.0  76283.0
12  771     NaN  191.0  97506.0
```

2. Conditionally combine columns `B_x` and `B_y` i.e. replace the `NaN` values in the left_table (*B_x*) with non-`NaN` values with right_table (*B_y*)

PS: Assume that both *B_x* and *B_y* are never simultaneously `NaN`

The End Result:

```py
      A      C       B
0   123    NaN    1819
1   456  115.0   41853
2   456  115.0   22723
3   456  115.0   57302
4   456  115.0   91494
5   789    NaN    9012
6   121    NaN    8732
7   883  171.0   43607
8   883  171.0   36327
9   771  191.0   39874
10  771  191.0   25456
11  771  191.0   76283
12  771  191.0   97506
```

I am aware of the function [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first), but it works **only with** `indices`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `merge` using `np.where`

```
df=pd.merge(df1, df2, on='C', how='left')
df['B']=np.where(df.B_x.isnull(),df.B_y,df.B_x)
df.drop(['B_x','B_y'],1,inplace=True)
df
Out[136]: 
      A      C        B
0   123    NaN   1819.0
1   456  115.0  41853.0
2   456  115.0  22723.0
3   456  115.0  57302.0
4   456  115.0  91494.0
5   789    NaN   9012.0
6   121    NaN   8732.0
7   883  171.0  43607.0
8   883  171.0  36327.0
9   771  191.0   8871.0
10  771  191.0   8871.0
11  771  191.0   8871.0
12  771  191.0   8871.0
```